# Copy font specs from Adobe XD to html/css

Tags: html, css, adobe

I have font specs in Adobe XD with screen width `1280px`

```
font: Bold 29px/43px Poppins;
letter-spacing: -0.87px;
```

And I want to copy this to work responsive in my html/css app, I tried copied it as it is, but doesn't work properly, I just searched for the font and here's its [link](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Poppins?selection.family=Poppins), How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need an html file where you include the Poppins font css file.
2. Then you need to set your media query to refer to your responsive mode.
3. And then with a simple class selector for the `text` element you assign the font values from AdobeXd.

```css
@media (max-width: 1280px) {
  .text {
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-weight: 700; /* Bold */
    font-size: 29px;
    line-height: 43px;
    letter-spacing: -0.87px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <p class="text">Some text</p>
</body>
</html>
```